# Wait VS Wait up

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

Please explain the difference between the following two sentences. Please try to explain it in simple words. Thanks.

1:- Don't wait up for me.

2:- Don't wait for me.

Comment: In almost all contexts, ***Don't wait up for me*** specifically means *Don't **stay up** past your normal bedtime waiting for me to arrive, just go to bed as usual*. But if you're out with a group of friends, and you're falling behind because they're walking faster than you, you might include the (optional) preposition in imperative ***Wait up!*** to mean *Hold up!, Rest up! **Stop moving** until I **catch up** with you*. But we wouldn't normally extend the utterance to *Wait up **for me*** in such contexts.

Answer (score 3):

In my (British) English, *wait up* has only one meaning: "not go to bed while waiting for somebody to arrive or return".

I don't know if it is used in other ways in other varieties of English (there are many phrasal verbs with *up*).